# Show that $I\subseteq I'$ iff $a'\leq a$ and $b\leq b'.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose that $I=[a,b]$ and $I'=[a',b']$ are closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $I\subseteq I'$ iff $a'\leq a$ and $b\leq b'.$

My attempt:

Assume $I\subseteq I'$. Then it must be that for every $x\in I=[a,b],$ we have $x\in I'=[a',b'] \implies$ $a'\leq a\leq x\leq b\leq b'. $ Thus we have $a'\leq a$ and $b\leq b'$.

Assume $a'\leq a$ and $b\leq b'$. Note that for any $x,y\in I=[a,b]$ with $x<y$ we have $$a'\leq a\leq x < y\leq b\leq b';$$ Thus $[x,y]\subseteq I'$. Hence $I\subseteq I'$.

Is this correct? I've been given guidance these are okay and are perfectly intuitive, but it feels like I'm using what I want to prove in the first proof.

In the second... I'm just not sure.

Could anyone verify this proof?

Comment: Your proof is correct, but I suggest that, in the case $I \subset I'$, it'd be better to consider $x = a$ and $x_{1} = b$ and apply the fact that $x, x_{1} \in I'$, then you conclude just like you did. Note that, it's not wrong your answer, this is just a suggestion for a better writing.

Comment: To expand on ABP's comment, you can prove the first case as: Suppose $I \subseteq I'$. Since $a, b \in I$, they must also be in $I'$. But by the definition of an interval $x \in I'$ if and only if $a' \le x$ and $x \le b'$, Therefore $a' \le a$ and $b \le b'$.